# Showing that these inner product induced norms are equivalent

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $T:H\to H$ be a self-adjoint isomorphism and suppose that $T$ is positive, that is, $\langle Tx,x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in H $. Define $$[x,y]= \langle Tx,y\rangle, x,y\in H,$$ and show that this is an inner product in $H$ an that the norm induced by this inner product and the original norm of $H$ are equivalent.

Let  $\|\cdot\|_0$ denote the norm induced by $[\cdot,\cdot]$ and $\|\cdot\|$ denote the original norm of H. I'm struggling to prove that $[x,x]>0$ for all $x\in H\backslash\{0\}$ and $\|\cdot\|\leq C\|\cdot \|_{0}$ for some constant $C>0$. I've done all the rest.

Comment: $T$ is bounded so $[x,x] \leq C \langle x, x \rangle$.  Once you know that $x \mapsto [x,x]^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a norm, that shows the two norms are equivalent, by the "bounded inverse theorem."

Comment: @fourierwho I've already shown this inequality. and you can't apply the bounded inverse theorem if you don't know if the space is still complete with the induced norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\lVert x\rVert^2 = \langle x,x\rangle = [T^{-1}x,x] \leqslant \lVert T^{-1}x\rVert_0\lVert x\rVert_0 \leqslant K\cdot \lVert T^{-1}x\rVert\cdot \lVert x\rVert_0 \leqslant K\cdot \lVert T^{-1}\rVert_{\text{op}} \lVert x\rVert\cdot\lVert x\rVert_0$$

by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for $[\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,]$, the inequality $\lVert y\rVert_0 \leqslant K\lVert y\rVert$, and the definition of the operator norm (with respect to $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$). For $x\neq 0$, we can divide by $\lVert x\rVert$ and obtain

$$\lVert x\rVert \leqslant K\cdot \lVert T^{-1}\rVert\cdot \lVert x\rVert_0\,.$$

This inequality is of course also true for $x = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! Now, the part I stucked first was showing that $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is indeed an inner product. Why $[x,x]>0$?

Comment: That follows from the final inequality. It is clear that $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is a positive *semi*definite sesquilinear form, and that gives us Cauchy-Schwarz. Of course we can also prove it in different ways. For example the spectrum of $T$ is contained in $[\varepsilon,\lVert T\rVert_{\text{op}}]$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, and that implies $\langle Tx,x\rangle \geqslant \varepsilon \lVert x\rVert^2$ by the spectral theory of self-adjoint operators.

Comment: But if we throw spectral theory at it, we might as well use the existence of square roots of positive self-adjoint operators and be done with writing $[x,x] = \langle Tx,x\rangle = \langle \sqrt{T}\,x,\sqrt{T}\,x\rangle$.

Comment: I was supposed to use only basic spectral theory  (for compact and self-adjoint operators). Further, what is a semidefinite sesquilinear form?

Comment: A sesquilinear form on a complex vector space $E$ is a map $E\times E \to \mathbb{C}$ that is linear in its first argument, and conjugate-linear [or antilinear] in the second. A sesquilinear form $S$ is positive semidefinite if $S(x,x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x\in E$. Positive definite would be $S(x,x) > 0$ for all $x \in E\setminus \{0\}$. So, just like an inner product, except that we don't require $S(x,x) = 0 \implies x = 0$. A positive semidefinite sesquilinear form is Hermitian, i.e. $S(x,y) = \overline{S(y,x)}$ for all $x,y\in E$.

Comment: If you're considering real Hilbert spaces, read "bilinear", but then one must explicitly mention the symmetry to have Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: I've found it in the Hans Whilhelm Alt's book (Linear Functional Analysis: An [...] Introduction, page 9 and Lemma 2.2 at page 10). There are proofs for these claims there... That helped a lot, thanks!!

Comment: [Link for the book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=mzilDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA432&lpg=PA432&dq="semidefinite+sesquilinear+form"&source=bl&ots=VHLlbgYWKD&sig=-v2a2ZuhaIZXc90hj0GStb-mNeI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8oMWvwvbYAhXJHpAKHS33CA8Q6AEwAXoECBEQAQ#v=onepage&q=2.2%20lemma&f=false)

Comment: So the self-adjointness is not used in this proof?

Comment: @user284331 We need the self-adjointness to have $[x,y] = \overline{[y,x]}$. If $T$ weren't self-adjoint, in the complex case $\langle Tx,x\rangle$ wouldn't even be real for all $x$.

Comment: @Filburt, are you sure you're only supposed to use the spectral theory of compact self-adjoint operators?  A compact self-adjoint operator is never an isomorphism.

Comment: @fourierwho the theory I am studying is for compact operators and for self-adjoint operators. The exercise, however, do not assume the operator to be compact... It couldn't be compact and isomorphism in infinite dimensional cases...

Comment: I think this exercise is very interesting. Start proving that $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is an inner product seems to be the natural approach, but, when done correctly, this is the last thing to conclude.

Comment: One can conclude it earlier if one wants to, @Filburt. From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality one has $[x,x] = 0 \implies (\forall y)([x,y] = 0)$, and then $[x,Tx] = \lVert Tx\rVert^2 > 0$ for $x\neq 0$ gives the positive definiteness. But since we can get everything we want at once, there's no need to split the argument to prove the sub-goals separately.

Comment: Yeap, I see... :-)